# Design database for category, subcategory and associated books

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I know there has been a few answer to a couple of questions similar to the one am asking. But their approach didn't look convincing.

My question is how would I structure a database for a category that can have books and a subcategory which can also have books?

I have already design a database, but am not convinced by the approach. So I would really appreciate if the guys with experience gave me some advice or improvement or a completely different approach.

This how my tables look like (bare in mind this is not the actual code)

```
TABLE Category
    ID
    user_id -- Foreign key from user
    name

TABLE SubCategory
    ID
    user_id
    category_id
    name
```

The table for the book have the same design.

Comment: It is interesting that the only place where `user_id` comes up in the question is in the table definitions, and you claim other solutions are not "professional".  Please fix your question so it actually explains the data that you want to represent.

Comment: You seemed to not have understood my question. Don't focus on the `user_id` that's not the problem. The question is how would I structure a database for a category that can have books and a subcategory which can also have books? In other words how would I have to design two tables for the sub category and parent category?

Comment: What is the relationship between categories and books? Is category (or subcategory) associated with a book or is book associated with a (sub)category? Which is the major entity and which the minor?

Comment: @TommCatt don't worry about it. I came up with a solutions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason to have more than one table for "categories", whether it be a top-level category or a sub-category.  They're all just "categories".

So, have a single table called "categories", with a `parent_id` field:

```
// categories table
id
name
user_id
parent_id
```

When you want to pull all top level categories, just run your query against the `categories` table with a condition that `parent_id` is null.

Then, when you want to pull sub categories, just run the query against the `categories` table with a condition that `parent_id = 123`  (or whatever).

Not only does this keep everything a lot cleaner, but it also allows for expansion in case you want to continue adding sub-sub-sub-sub categories...etc.

---

Another option is to use [CakePHP's TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html).

I personally just rather use the way I suggested above, but might just be because I haven't taken the time to really understand this behavior enough.

Comment: Fair enough, how would you do for the books? Lets say what if I want to add a book to a parent category and I also have the option to add to the one that is not a parent, how would I do it?

Comment: You'd have a join table called `books_categories`, and keep a row for each association between a book and a category.   id, book_id, category_id  How you add the rows is up to you, but once the structure is there, it should be pretty self explanatory.  If it's not, feel free to write up another question about that specifically.

Comment: `INDEX(parent_id)` is needed.

Comment: I would be very, very, very careful about using such a solution.  MySQL has basically no support for hierarchal data structures or recursive queries, so using this structure is probably going cause problems.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've used it on a number of fairly large projects without any apparent downside.  Not sure what kind of "problems" you're referring to, but I haven't seen them.

Comment: @Dave . . . Try getting the list of all subcategories (down the tree) for a given category.  Or, try determining if two things are in the same high-level categories based on their subcategories.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - if those are things you think you might need to do, then by all means, use the TreeBehavior that I mentioned.  That's what it's for.  But like I said, I've made a number of pretty large projects, and those concerns you mention were not ones I would need to deal with, so I decided to go option 1.  I think instead of saying "MySQL has no support... this structure is going to cause problems", you could have just said "be careful to make sure you understand your project needs before deciding on going method 1, as it may limit your available queries in some cases"

Answer (score 2):

If `parent_category` is null then it is a top level.  If it is non-null then it is a sub category.

```
TABLE Category
  ID
  name
  parent_category
```