# Database table design of a settings system

Tags: sql, database-design

Can you please help me with my database design I'm trying to do a mini system which includes a Category, and under ONE category has many subcategory, and under ONE subcategory has many topics, and under ONE topic has many questions. So I'm going to put Add buttons for four of them `Category > SubCategory > SubCategoryTopic > Question`

All of them have to be dynamic obviously but I was planning to display it as a dropdown then I thought that it wouldn't look friendly when there are many topics stored, but  I was wondering if you  could help me with my database table design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design database for category, subcategory and associated books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198559/design-database-for-category-subcategory-and-associated-books)

Comment: no sir @AndréFerraz

Comment: @ranger Rather than just asserting that it is not a duplicate please explain how the linked question/answer did not help you so that we might be able to help. From what I understand the linked question's accepted answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  Obviously it is very bare-bones, but the relationships are all there: [image: Category-Topic-Question ERD]

I'm not too clear on what you mean by "planning to display 'it' as a dropdown".  I think paged listings would be much better than a dropdown, but I'm not too sure what you are going for.

Comment: Can you include subcategory as well? Yeah at first I planned to put a dynamic dropdown for each table so if I choose a category from a drop down, the second dropdown will echo subcategory info under that category, then the third dropdown will echo subcategorytopic fields from database under that sub category and lastly 4th dropdown will echo question under that subcattopic. All this is for my settings on survey system @Aaron Dressler

Comment: In this design, subcategory can be represented without creating an extra subcategory table.  If a "category" is a "subcategory", then it will have an ID of the "parent" category in the ParentCategoryID field (a self-referencing relationship).  If there is no subcategory, then the SubCategoryID field will be NULL.  You can do the dropdown you mentioned by using AJAX to first fetch the categories without a ParentCategoryID (ParentCategoryID == NULL).  Once a selection is made, poll the server for subcategories whose ParentCategoryID = Selected ID.  Repeat this strategy for topic and question.

Comment: Of course, if you absolutely need to add a separate table for SubCategory, then replace ParentCategoryID FK with SubCategoryID, create a table like Category called SubCategory, add additional fields, and just point the topics FK to the SubCategoryID instead of CategoryID.

Comment: will do thank you!!. I just thought that the dropdowns will look bad especially if many datas are stored. What do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: Not too sure.  This structure is very flexible though.  So if you needed to move away from dropdowns because they become too cluttered, you can easily use bootstrap panels, accordions, or even separate pages.