# How to store a variable list in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

im not very familiar with mysql, i had following problem. I would store some products in a mysql. These products have a bunch of subproducts and how could i store these subproducts

should i do a row for every subproduct but every product have different set of subproducts.
Or is it better to use a noSql database for such data

```
product
   productName
   productDescription
   productDimension
   subProducts
      1
      2
      3
   price
```

thanks for help

Comment: I'd consider a product table and separate product_subproduct table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can have subproducts in a separate table, and use a FOREIGN KEY reference to a product ID in the main products table.

If product properties are somewhat similar, you can also have them in the same table, but using a parentID column to reference a parent product. You can then use FOREIGN KEY to enforce constraints even if it is the same table. Products that are not subproducts can have parentID of NULL.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES products (productID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And for example:

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('p1', 'Product 1', '55 dm3', 59.99, 1, NULL);
...
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('p1-1', 'Subproduct 1.1', '8 dm3', 19.99, 4, 1);
...

mysql> SELECT * FROM products WHERE parentID = 1;
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
| productName | productDescription | productDimension | price | productID | parentId |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
| p1-1        | Subproduct 1.1     | 8 dm3            | 19.99 |         4 |        1 |
| p1-2        | Subproduct 1.2     | 4 dm3            | 19.99 |         5 |        1 |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------+-------+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to trade off the advantage of relational tables and rather go with more flexible JSON data, MySQL 5.7 supports that too. Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

You can for instance have a JSON object representing a product, which contains an array of subproduct objects.

Comment: Ok thats it. Unfortunately, its not possible to switch to an noSql database. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MySQL Relationships. By using foreign keys to relate your tables. You should have 2 tables. 1 for your main product and another table for your subproducts.

Product Table:

products

---

id 
name

Sub-product table:

---

id
parent_product_id
name

Visit this link. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-foreign-key-relationships.html

Answer (score 0):

you will get reference from 
[Design database for category, subcategory and associated books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198559/design-database-for-category-subcategory-and-associated-books)
like: 
TABLE Category
  ID
  name
  parent_category